# React native and onesignal notification problem

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, onesignal

Hi firstly I learning react-native and I use onesignal for notification everything awesome but 
sometimes iphone 6s hasnt token one signal error is 'Apns Delegate Never Fired'  but 6 plus alwasy has a token  and background notification very nice. If the application is open while sending a notification, the notification does not occur above. It occurs on a dialog screen.[image: Like this]

```html
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"doyurunbenicomproje"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption=2 I aded this code and  notifications will display as normal notifications.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your os version between on 6s and 6plus.
2. If the app is foreground,notification will show on your screen, if the app is background,notification will show above.

**EDIT**
add this code to your `AppDelegate.m`

```
 (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError %@", error);
}
```

Comment: 1 .6 plus ios 12 6 s 13 but  6s yesterday has token now hasnt 2. In applications made with react native, notifications always appear above

Comment: I added my code  but I never change  app delegate because one signal cannot need change app delegate code  I use this document just ios https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

Comment: I have solution